# How to add comments restricted to team members on any JIRA

Tags: python, jira

I am working on a project to add comments on JIRA programmatically based on certain conditions, fields of the JIRA. Can anyone tell me how to add comments on JIRA using python that are restricted to team members only? I tried the following:

```
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
issue = jira.issue('ISSUE-1764')
jira.add_comment(issue,'test1',None,True)
```

Comments are getting added but they are visible to all. Saw it [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-Python-add-comment-does-not-post-as-internal-comment/qaq-p/888442#U1039983) but I havent got working response yet. I tried flipping `None` to Roles but it didnt help.

Can anyone please help?